# How to increase the value of a variable everytime grep finds something

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Suppose that you are passing a file to `grep word` and want to find out how many occurrences of `word` there are in the file. How can I increase the value of a variable **while** grep is working?

So for example, if there are three occurrences of `word`, I would like to have an output such as

```
1
2
3
```

printed on the `stout` (or saved into a variable).

Comment: What about two matches on a single line then?do you want the count to be increased even for thta extra match on the same line?

Comment: @sarathi not in this case, since the word I am looking for is usually always at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
$ cat file
word
bird
is
this
word
word word word

$ fgrep -o word file | awk '{print NR}'
1
2
3
4
5
```

If you only want to count the lines with a match and not each match then drop the `-o` option:

```
$ fgrep word file | awk '{print NR}'
1
2
3
```

If you just want to save the total count to a variable:

```
$ count=$(fgrep -o word file | wc -l)

$ echo $count
5

$ count=$(grep -c word file)

$ echo $count
3
```

Increment variable:

```
#/bin/bash

while read line; do 
    fgrep -q word <<< "$line" && ((count++)) 
done < file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I wanted to save the count to a variable, incrementing it in every step?

Comment: What would be the point you'd overwrite  `1` with `2` with `3` and only get the final count anyway?

Comment: Because in this case I would need to pass the intermediate values to zenity to display the percentage of a progress bar...

Comment: One last question :D would it be possible to use echo instead of awk? Because as far as I understand, zenity's progress bar works on echoed results..

Comment: You misunderstand, `echo` and `awk` both print to `stdout`.

Comment: I know, but writing `echo '{$1}'` prints exactly `{$1}` and not an increasing number like with `awk`

Comment: So if this is true, do you have any idea why the following code does not work? `7z a -t7z /home/user/Desktop/Backup.7z /home/user/Desktop/folder_to_backup -mx9 | fgrep Compressing | nl | awk '{print $1}' | zenity --progress --percentage=0 --auto-close`? It should use the output coming from awk do display the progression, but it doesn't...

Comment: My guess without knowing anything about "7z" or "zenity" is that either the word Compressing doesn't appear in the output of 7z or some buffering is happening. Let's start by changing `fgrep Compressing | nl | awk '{print $1}'` to just `awk '/Compressing/{print ++c,$1}'` so we get rid of the unnecessary commands and pipes and let us know if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

considering the response of the comment:

```
grep word file|awk '{print NR}'
```